# Overwrite all columns of a matrix with a vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, octave, overwrite

I try to overwrite my matrix columns with a vector without using `for`-loops. Is this possible?

```
close all;clc; clear all;
A = pascal(5);
v = zeros(1,5);

A(1,:) = v; %// this works fine
A(:,:) = v; %// this do not work
```

Can I overwrite all columns in the matrix `A` with vector `v` in one command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `repmat` to recreate `A` by repeating `v`

```
A = repmat(v, size(A,1), 1)
```

or in your example case just

```
A = zeros(size(A))
```

or

```
A = A*0
```

Comment: @metty sorry I misread your `v` as a column vector. Try my edit.

Comment: No problem, if it helped then consider [accepting the answer](https://www.google.co.za/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=accepting%20and%20answer)